# JQuery UI automcomplete- automcomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use Jquery autocomplete, but get the following:

```
Timestamp: 5/05/2013 11:45:10 PM
Error: TypeError: jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function
Source File: xxx/test/wp-content/themes/maths-aust/js-files/checkout-suburb-lookup.js
Line: 31
```

The head of the HTML looks fine:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='xxx/test/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx/test/wp-content/themes/xxx/js-files/jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx/test/wp-content/themes/xxx/js-files/checkout-suburb-lookup.js"></script>
```

Script looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
  jQuery(function() {     
      jQuery( "#wpsc_checkout_form_22" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
              featureClass: "P",
              style: "full",
              maxRows: 12,
              name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
              response( jQuery.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                return {
                  label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                  value: item.name
                }
              }));
            }
          });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          //
        },
        open: function() {
          jQuery( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
          jQuery( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
      });
    });
});
```

I am stumped as to why it can't find the autocomplete plugin!

Comment: Yep look at my question- I've included the necessary declarations above in the correct order.

Comment: have you confirmed that your jQueryUI build actually contains the autocomplete feature? Have you checked that the jqueryUI script file is loading correctly (look in the browser dev tools in case it's giving a 404 error or anything like that).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Turns out Wordpress already included the UI!